# A iterative and lagging function similar to diff in R, but not just difference?

Tags: r

The diff function in R returns suitably lagged and iterated differences.

```
x = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 11, 7, 5)
diff(x)
# [1]  1 -1  2  8 -4 -2
diff(x, lag=2)
[1]  0  1 10  4 -6
```

Is there anyway to customize this so that we can use functions other than difference? For example, sum:

```
itersum(x)
# 3 3 4 14 18 12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollapply`

```
require(zoo)
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 11, 7, 5)
rollapply(x, width = 2, FUN = sum)
## [1]  3  3  4 14 18 12
```

Answer (score 8):

In base R, there is the `filter` function. It is not as friendly and general as `zoo::rollapply` but it is extremely fast. In your case, you are looking to apply a convolution filter with weights `c(1, 1)`:

```
itersum <- function(x, n = 2) tail(filter(x, rep(1, n)), sides = 1), -(n-1))

itersum(x)
# 3 3 4 14 18 12
```

To give you more ideas, here is how the `diff` and `cumsum` functions can be re-written in terms of `filter`:

```
diff   <- function(x) head(filter(x, c(1, -1)), -1)
cumsum <- function(x) filter(x, 1, method = "recursive")
```

---

In general, if you are looking to *roll* a binary function, then `head` and `tail` is probably the easiest and fastest way to go as it will take advantage of vectorized functions:

```
itersum     <- function(x) tail(x, -1) + head(x, -1)
diff        <- function(x) tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1)
sign.change <- function(x) tail(sign(x), -1) != head(sign(x), -1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a bit more on the 'filter coefficients'? It looks difficult to grasp.

Comment: Also, what if I would like to have the products of each consecutive pair?

Comment: I know, that's what I meant by *not as friendly*... Have a look at the doc and the formula for the convolution filter. In your case, you want `y[i] = f[1]*x[i] + f[2]*x[i-1]` where `f[1]` and `f[2]` are both `1`. So the `filter` argument needs to be `c(1, 1)`. See what `filter(x, c(1, 1))` gives. Then the `tail` and `sides` arg I used are just a way to deal with the `NA` you might get at the tails.

Comment: Regarding your question about products. You can only apply linear filters with `filter`. That's what I meant by *not as general*. The upside is that it is really way, way faster in terms of computation times.  I'll point out that if you wanted to do the product between consecutive items, I would use `head` and `tail` again as it will be a lot faster: `head(x, -1) * tail(x, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I asked this question to figure out how to register sign changes in a vector of numbers, thanks to @dickoa 's answer, I got it done this way:

```
require(zoo)
equals = function(x) all(diff(x) == 0)
x = c(2, 3, -1, 3, -2, -5)
y = sign(x)
rollapply(y, 2, equals)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `head(y, -1) == tail(y, -1)` will be infinitely faster (or close.) It's always worth stating your initial intent in your original question. In fact, you should have edited your question rather than post this as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, I will do as you said next time.